# Binding of Control parameter returns NULL while using HTTP POST

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller with a method that returns some response based on the value of a parameter. I am trying to POST Json data to this controller but somehow the binding is not working. I am using Fiddler to test my controller method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public string Authenticate(string username)
{
    //some logic
    return "value";
}
```

now userName always returns null when I debug the application. To test this method  I am using Fiddler. Raw data of the request is :

```
POST http://localsite/Home/authenticate HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:52774
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 20
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json

{"username":"kunal"}
```

Any guesses where I am going wrong in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC2 there is no model binder support for JSON out of the box.

If you don't plan to upgrade to MVC3/4 then you can find a good article: [Sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) how to enable it in an MVC2 app.

Basically you need to create and add a `JsonValueProviderFactory` to the `ValueProviderFactories`...

Luckily you can find a implementation in [ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures library](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742#DownloadId=110348)

Comment: Is formscollection the only way then to receive posted values?

Comment: If you don't want to use the `JsonValueProviderFactory` which is described in the linked article then I guess yes.